# Deserialize NaN, Infinity using Json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

Need to convert **NaN** in Json(as it is not JSON) to Double in Json4s without using jackson.

For example, I am having following JSON:

```
{ "a": NaN }
```

I need to parse above json using JSON4S.

Can we write any deserializer if possible for this?

Comment: There is no way to do that because json4s parser doesn't know how to read NaN values.

Comment: @SebastianCelestino Is there any workaround to solve this?

Comment: Here is a branch with changes in json4s that you need https://github.com/scelestino/json4s/tree/feature-NaN-support, but I think that is a change that cannot be done official because jackson doesn't support NaN (json4s works with both of them, native and jackson)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this from the version `3.6.7`:

```scala
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val json = """{"a": "NaN"}"""
  println(parse(json))
 // Displays
 // JObject(List((a,JString(NaN))))
}
```